# Configurable factory in Kotlin for JavaScript

Tags: kotlin

I have a Kolin class A whose property is either supplied in a primary constructor, or is created by a factory in the secondary constructor of A.

```
interface I

class O : I

class A (val i: I) {
    constructor(): this(factory!!.create())
}

interface Factory {
    fun create(): I
}

class MyFactory: Factory {
    override fun create(): I {
        return O()
    }
}

var factory: Factory? = null

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    factory = MyFactory()
    A()
}
```

When I compile this code to JavaScript (Kolin Compiler version 1.0.6-release-127) and run it in a browser (Safari 10.0.3), I get the following runtime error:

```
ReferenceError:Can't find variable: tmp$0
```

The error occurs in the secondary constructor of A. It seems that Kolin has a problem in performing the null check of a parameter in the secondary constructor. The code runs correctly when I change the factory declaration to "not null" and remove the factory initialization from the main() method:

```
val factory: Factory = MyFactory()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    A()
}
```

But this is not what I want, since I want to be able to configure the factory at application startup time.

Do I miss something, or is this a bug in Kotlin's JavaScript compiler? Does anybody know a workaround for this problem? Is there another or better way to design configurable factories in Kotlin for JavaScript?

Generated JavaScript code:

```
var KotlinTest = function (Kotlin) {
  'use strict';
  var _ = Kotlin.defineRootPackage(function () {
    this.factory = null;
  }, /** @lends _ */ {
    I: Kotlin.createTrait(null),
    O: Kotlin.createClass(function () {
      return [_.I];
    }, function O() {
    }),
    A: Kotlin.createClass(null, function A(i) {
      this.i = i;
    }),
    A_init: function ($this) {
      $this = $this || Object.create(_.A.prototype);
      _.A.call($this, ((tmp$0 = _.factory) != null ? tmp$0 : Kotlin.throwNPE()).create());
      return $this;
    },
    Factory: Kotlin.createTrait(null),
    MyFactory: Kotlin.createClass(function () {
      return [_.Factory];
    }, function MyFactory() {
    }, /** @lends _.MyFactory.prototype */ {
      create: function () {
        return new _.O();
      }
    }),
    main_kand9s$: function (args) {
      _.factory = new _.MyFactory();
      _.A_init();
    }
  });
  Kotlin.defineModule('KotlinTest', _);
  _.main_kand9s$([]);
  return _;
}(kotlin);
```

Comment: It seems like a bug in Kotlin's Javascript compiler for version 1.0.6. I tried your example with both version 1.0.6 and the 1.1-beta, and it works with the latter version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. As @marstran correctly commented, this seems to be a bug in Kolin's Javascript compiler 1.0.6 which seems to be fixed in 1.1-beta. In the meantime, I'm using a workaround similar to the following:

```
interface I

class O : I

class A (val i: I) {
    constructor(): this(Factory.get().create())
}

interface Factory {

    companion object {
        private var IMPL : Factory? = null
        fun get(): Factory = IMPL!!
        fun set(impl: Factory) {
            IMPL = impl
        }
    }

    fun create(): I
}

class MyFactory: Factory {
    override fun create(): I {
        return O()
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Factory.set(MyFactory())
    A()
}
```